# How to use annotation TypeDefs in Kotlin?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin

What is the equivalent Kotlin code of this Java snippet?

```
@Data
@Entity
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "int-array", typeClass = IntArrayType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    //....
}
```

finally following code works.

```
@TypeDefs(
        TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType::class),
        TypeDef(name = "int-array", typeClass = IntArrayType::class),
        TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType::class),
        TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
)
```

Comment: Did you try something? What is your problem?

Answer (score 12):

Try this.

```
@Data
@Entity
@TypeDefs(
  TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType::class.java),
  TypeDef(name = "int-array", typeClass = IntArrayType::class.java),
  TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType::class.java),
  TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class.java))
class Parent : Serializable
```

Comment: @HaifengZhang you may remove it, if the library supports `KClass<*>`

Comment: Remove the .java then it is compile-time static